# Python syntax error in Atom when running multiple line statements

Tags: python, atom-editor

**Question:** How do you execute multiple line Python statements in Atom?

I am using `Atom` as a Python IDE on Windows. I have not been able to figure out how to execute multiple line statements like the following:

```
is_hot = True
if is_hot:
    print("It's a hot day.")
```

Specifically, if I run line two (Hydrogen:run-and-move-down; shift-enter on Windows), I encounter a syntax error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-2e8a724ca55e>", line 1
    if is_hot:
              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Basically, it seems like Atom/Hydrogen/language-python are not interpreting indentation correctly. To troubleshoot this issue I restored Atom to its default settings by uninstalling Atom, deleting the `.Atom` file (containing packages and settings), and then reinstalling Atom. I then installed the `Hydrogen` package and set my language to Python. The problem persists.

I have seen some discussion of similar issues on Github, e.g. [here](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/724). But, I have not been able to resolve the issue. Of note, I cannot find the `Add foldEndPattern` setting within the atom/language-python settings as referenced in the GitHub Issue.

I can create a GitHub issue, but I figured I'd ask here first.

Comment: I don't know **Atom**, but it sounds to me like what **Atom** is doing is considering just the line you're on to be a complete program.  It's not considering the next line at all.  If this were the case, like if you put just this line in a "test.py" file and ran it, that error is what I would expect that you'd get. - I've used similar systems.  I think with what I've used, you need to **select the lines you want to run**, and run some menu command or press a particular keysroke.

Comment: Hi Steve, you are correct in that either selecting the entire multi line statement and running that or saving the file and running it would work. However, this really seems to weaken Atom's usability as an IDE in my mind! Im really hoping there is a setting or something in Atom that I can change to make this work.

Comment: I think maybe this is a bug.  Just for yucks, I installed Atom on my Mac.  The key bindings seem to be different, but the main "run" binding works fine for me with your program.  I do CMD-I and your program runs fine, no matter what line I'm on.  Only if I make a selection does CMD-I then only run the code I've selected.  So unless you're selecting just the second line, it seems this should be working.

Comment: btw, when I select just the second line, I get a different error, one about indentation.  Since you're getting an error about EOF, that seems to pretty clear to me that it thinks that the code ends at the point where it has pointed to with the carat. - I can find no way to get that particular error.

Comment: Thanks for trying Steve. What is the keybinding of CMD+I on your mac?

Answer (score 0):

You should first see if you python code runs in Atom without Hydrogen. Load the Atom package Script and after its loaded it should show up under the Packages menu item. Select Script under package menu and use "run Script". The [Script package can be downloaded here](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=Script).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Hydrogen troubleshooting specifically about not recognizing Python

https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/Troubleshooting.html#hydrogen-does-not-recognize-python

Comment: I think it's finding Python ok, because the error he's getting is a Python interpreter error.